# Where to place this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74595/more-realistic-strength-stat

**Worldbuilding:** It's too RPG-like.
**RPG:** D&D and reality can't be correlated, as long as the wisdom stat lives.
**Biology:** But it's for fictional system.

**Where to ask this question?**

Comment: This question with significant refactoring might work on worldbuilding. Let me think on it and I might come back with something.

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to get answered?  The question in the link is a bit unclear to me and I am not sure what you are trying to solve for.

Answer (score 5):

## There is no rule saying that there will be Stack Exchange site for your question.

Only answer I can give is - nowhere on SE, because it's bad question on all sites it might touch.

### Not here

It does not belong to worldbuilding because you are not building any world, just putting some numbers on things that actually exists, and these numbers won't even exist in your world.

### Not on biology

It does not touch the biological aspect of strength. At all.

### Not on RPG with D&D tag

Sorry, but D&D never aimed at replicating reality. It's just a game system, a way to create stories, not a reality simulator. And you pretty much will get the same answer under other systems.

### Rethink your idea, maybe?

For a roleplaying game, do you even need to have physics behind that stat?! Would your players bother, or get bored? I bet it's the latter. That's why most of the RPG systems are more about play and less about reality. Too much reality gets tiresome, boring, and slow.

Comment: Physics StackExchange?

Comment: Nope. Not some arbitrary fictional thing.

Answer (score 5):

There are a large number of problems with your question, the main one being that it's not actually about worldbuilding. You also throw in a lot of extraneous fluff that detracts from the question rather than helping.

A better question would read something like:

> In many classic RPGs character's abilities are measured using a set of statistics such as Strength. Those have a numbered score and influence all the related tasks accordingly.
>
> I'm building a world where these statistics are not just a real thing but are known about by the inhabitants. They know that they have "Strength 13" for example.

This explains the background without forcing people to read through lots of irrelevant text. It also makes it clear that this is a question about building a world.

Now you need to ask the question though. It needs to be **one** question and ideally it needs to have a way to find a "best" answer and rate the answers against each other.

For example **one** of the following might be used:

> How would this effect employment in this world? Might people be expected to have or demonstrate certain scores?

or:

> Is this a realistic possibility? Can things like Strength and Intelligence be measured objectively?

You would still need to explain what you are looking for in a "best" answer though to either of these questions.